# Realtime with PubSubHubbub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, real-time, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement real time chat engine with PubSubHubbub as the core in Rails. My question is what I need to do to or read to achieve this task ? Where I'm gonna start ? What knowledge do I need to know first because I'm really really newbie in this field and like to play with it... or are they any realtime chat engine that is fully compatible with Rails other than pshb ?

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you check out [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) there is a good library called [XMPP4R](http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/). XMPP is what Google IM uses and there are a bunch of existing clients and IM gateways that support it so you'd be able to very rapidly do things like hook up your program to IM you when a certain event happens.

It is my understanding that [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) (as a protocol) is designed less for things like chat (1 to 1 communications) and more for situations where you would previously have to poll a resource for updates (like a series of RSS subscriptions).

Comment: Thanks Mike, and really right now I'm very confused and it seem I'm in a wrong direction. What I want is just a simple chat engine and It seem you are right, pubsubhubbub is like realtime between machine/Website or several domain... and after researching, I found Ajax Push engine (APE/Comet technology) and Kaazing Gateway (html5 web socket), plus your xmpp4r, which one do you think easy to implement ?

Comment: I think you need to define "chat engine" more precisely, this is all right tool for the job type items: XMPP4R if you want to connect to existing IM tools, APE/Comet+Kaazing if you want a web page that different people are chatting on and PubSubHubBub if you want near real time notifications across publishers. 

Choosing the right tool for what you want to accomplish is the easiest thing.